# input form with HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: php, http-status-code-405

I wrote a very simple php script to log some information in a log file.

```
<?php
  $log_file_name = 'mylog.log'; // Change to the log file name
  $message = $_POST['userName']; // incoming message
  file_put_contents($log_file_name, $message, FILE_APPEND);
  header('Location: index.html'); // redirect back to the main site
?>
```

And I just want to post some information from the following input form:

```
<form action="save-to-log.php" method="POST">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

But I have the following error when I try:

HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

The code works locally (with XAMPP) but not when I try on a real server.

Comment: Open a dev console (chrome's one is good) and check that the Request URL is correct for the network request.

Comment: @noahnu I did what you proposed and the request url is correct, I can even download the php script with the url and it contains the correct code. It's as if the php file was unable to deal with post

Comment: I have the following message in the console:
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/binary: "http://lrese.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lrese/files/SPECDO/save-to-log.php".

Comment: Maybe a conflicting htaccess/rewrite? At some point, some script is serving the PHP file as `application/binary` instead of passing it to PHP. I.e. PHP is never **parsing** the file. I don't know enough about how your website is setup. Side note: You should **NEVER** be able to download the PHP file by a simple HTTP request.

Comment: @noahnu and do you think that there is a possibility to explicitely write that the script is a php script (beginning of the file for example)?

Comment: Are you using some sort of PHP framework? Do you have any other PHP scripts on your server that work? If you're using a framework, are you sure you're implementing your form scripts correctly? Edit the question to include that information.

Comment: @noahnu Thank you for your help. The problem was simple PHP and MySQL were not possible with this server. I feel stupid now :)